# Angular.js: TrackBy doesn't prevent full *ngFor-generated list refresh

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have code, which prints words of a simple sentence in an ul-list, so that you can remove any of the items and then insert it back:

```js
  arr = ['hi', 'i', 'am', 'an' ,'item', 'too'].map(function (word) {
    return {value: word}
  });
  trackByFn (item : any) {
    return item.value;
  }
  
  removed   : any = null;
  removed_i : any = null;
  removeItem (i : number) {
    this.removed_i = i;
    this.removed = this.arr.splice(i, 1);
  }
  insert () {
    this.arr.splice(this.removed_i, 0, this.removed);
  }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of arr; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
      {{item.value}}
      <button *ngIf="!removed" (click)="removeItem(i)">Remove</button>
    </li>
</ul>
<button *ngIf="removed" (click)="insert()">Insert</button>
```

It resulted in 2 issues:

1. I tried to do it with *trackBy* feature. My *trackByFn* returns *item.value* as an *"id"* but still when list is re-rendered after invoking *insert(...)*, there are always several *li*-s updated (checked via Browser Console)!
2. Moreover, the inserted item does not contain *{{item.value}}*, which is interpolated into it!

Please, can somebody explains what's going on?

**UPDATE**

I have changed *trackBy-function* and added a button with *full_refresh()* reaction.

```html
<button (click)="full_refresh()">Random refresh</button>
```

```js
full_refresh () {
    var prevSource = this.source, prevLength = prevSource.length;
    var source = this.source = new Array(prevLength);
    for (let i = 0; i < prevLength; i++)
      source[i] = {value: prevSource[i].value + prevSource[i].value};
  }

  trackBy (i : number, word : any) {
    return i; // UPDATE 3: corrected according to Siddhant's note
  }
```

So, now I have changed the *trackBy-function* (now it returns *index* with purpose) and added a full refresh button, each of which replaces both *old array* and *array objects* with *entirely new ones*. So, *new array objects* have nothing to do with the *old ones*, so == should return *false*. Then Angular is supposed to check *trackBy-function*, right? And *trackBy-function* returns array *index*, so each *new object* should be recognized as "identical" to the corresponding *old object* in array, right? But still I get complete refresh of the elements! And also, an error pops up in console:

*Can't bind to 'ngForNgTrackBy' since it isn't a known property of 'li'.*

**UPDATE 2:**

Just found out that function *trackBy* isn't called at all. When I add *console.log(...)* into it nothing gets logged when I commit full_refresh, which changes *source*, which is then printed as a list via *ngFor*.

Moreover, when I change function name like this (please, see *ngTrackBy: trackByByeByeBye* in the end of the *ngFor* statement), app gets compiled but in the console there appears the error: *Can't bind to 'ngForNgTrackBy' since it isn't a known property of 'li'.*

```js
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let word of source; let i = index; trackBy: trackByByeByeBye">
  <!--there should be trackBy <<actual property>> : trackBy <<corresponding method>>-->
    {{word.value}}
    <button (click)="remove(i)">Remove</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**ANSWER**

Please, see the last comment to Saddhant's reply! It is there! :) Above you see the code, which's already been corrected! Enjoy your day! :)

Comment: Your trackByFn is not correctly closed.

Comment: You are using `item.item` within interpolation and not `item.value`

Comment: Thank you for your super-fast response! I am sorry for these typos. They were made when copying code here, the source file doesn't contain any of these mistakes. And still when compiled the source code leads to all the issues mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `{{item.value}}` doesn't print the value after insert is because the value inserted is an array and not an object containing `value` property.

```ts
// splice returns an array of deleted elements
this.removed = this.arr.splice(i, 1);
// this.removed would be [{value: 'deletedValue'}]

// You can use this.removed[0] when inserting
this.arr1.splice(this.removed_i, 0, this.removed[0]);
// In case if this.removed contains multiple elements, you can use spread operator as ...this.removed
```

In your example, using `trackBy` doesn't really help in any way and is not required as you are mutating the same array and playing around with same object references. Since object references within the array remain same, Angular automatically would be able to handle unnecessary re-creation of DOM nodes.

Also `trackByFn` written in your case won't work as expected, because the 1st argument passed to `trackByFn` is the index.

The proper way to write the function would be:

```ts
trackByFn (index: number, item : any) {
  return item.value;
}
```

---

**Edit:** For the new issue added to the post

Since you are now creating a new array with new references, using `trackBy` will make sense in this scenario.

To your point of why the elements are getting refreshed?
You are using `word.value` within trackByFn and since you have changed the `value` within the new object, Angular will consider it as a new record and re-create the element.

```ts
// The 'value' which is being used in trackByFn is now changed
{value: prevSource[i].value + prevSource[i].value}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! With yor advise I got rid of the 1st problem!
And now I also understand why the trackByFn didn't work :)

Comment: But now I have changed the trackBy-function trackBy-function seems to be useless (because 2 its equal results for 2 different objects still leads to replacement). Please, see the post update.

Comment: @Daniil I have updated my answer. Also regarding the error you are getting, it's really difficult to tell anything without looking at the code. Can you please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on an online IDE like [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)

Comment: Siddhant, thank you so much for your time and attention!
Read your edit. You're right, I forgot to change "return item.value" to "return i" in function trackBy! Now I have corrected it in app and in post. This helped. But there was one more mistake, which is so unsmart! I wrote ngTrackBy (instead of trackBy!) in ngFor! The error actually said about it. Now I see. And now everything works fine. With index as a "unique tracking id" <li>-s do not get recreated each refresh but still their content is updated! Seems like in case of matching "trackby ids" Angular updates the inner tree, right?

Comment: I would like to increase your answer rating but I cannot (because I have less than 15 points)! Thank you a lot any way! You solved my day! :)

Comment: So, now I can increase answer reputation! +1 from me :)

Comment: @Daniil Seems like in case of matching "trackby ids" Angular updates the inner tree, right? --> Updates do happen as per Change Detection. `trackBy` helps in avoiding unnecessary recreation of DOM nodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, Siddhant! Now everything is super-clear!